# Loop through config.ini file in python

Tags: python, config, ini, configparser

I'm trying to loop through my config.ini file using values in that same config.ini file.

In my config.ini file I have the following:

```
[Machine_List]
List = Machine01,Machine02,Machine03
 
[SQL_Query]
Machine01 = SELECT...
Machine02 = SELECT...
Machine03 = SELECT...
```

In my Python code that I've tried:

```
Machine_List = config['Machine_List']['List']
for x in Machine_List.split(','):
   Query = config['SQL_Query'][x]
```

The goal is be able to add an item to the [Machine_List] List and its corresponding [SQL_Query] in the config.ini file and have python loop through each one.

After the "Query" variable is defined I use it to generate a dataframe and save that as an html file. I need a separate html file for each listed item in [Machine_List] List.

I get an error for the line Query = config['SQL_Query'][x]

The rest of my code is inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to `zip` the Machines list together with queries:

```py
Machine_List = config['Machine_List']['List']
for machine, query in zip(Machine_List.split(','), config['SQL_Query']):
    # do something
```